# Order parent model based on child model creation date in eager load laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Conversation` model like this :

```
class Conversation extends Model
{
        protected $primaryKey = 'conversation_id';
        public function questions (){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Question','conversation_id','conversation_id');
        }

    public function latestQuestion ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Question','conversation_id','conversation_id')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

}
```

And a `Question` model like this :

```
class Question extends Model
    {    
        protected $primaryKey = 'question_id';

        public function conversation ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Conversation', 'conversation_id', 'conversation_id');
        }
}
```

As you can see each Conversation can have some Question.

Furthermore, Conversation  model has a `latestQuestion` relationship that fetches latest Question for that Conversation.

Now I want to list all Conversations with their latest question.

For that I wrote :

```
$conversations =
    Conversation::
    with('latestQuestion')
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

above code, orders conversations by their `created_at` field.

But I want to make a list of Conversations that conversations with new question be on top of list. in fact I want to order Conversations based On latest Question `created_at` field But I do not know How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Join Query. Because Eager Loading will just bring the base table and fetch the referenced table records later

```
 Conversation::join('questions', 'conversations.conversation_id', '=', 'questions.conversation_id')
            ->orderBy('questions.created_at','Desc')
            ->groupBy('conversations.conversation_id')
            ->get();
```